# Is this a bug when Constraint from one textfield applies to others on other form

Tags: lwuit, lwuit-resource-editor, lwuit-textfield

I've tested so many times and get strange behavior.Lwuit version 1.5.

I've created few `Form` with `TextFields` on them.(Form1, Form2, Form3).
When I set a numeric constraint to one of the `TextFields` on the Form1 by Resource Editor, then run MIDP application with form1 it works fine but when user go to Form2, all the `TextFields` becomes with numeric constraint without of ability to change the input order by user. and when go back to Form1 `TextFields` becomes with numeric constraint too.
I've tested it without any additional code. All navigation by Resource Editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting constraints to the TextFields in the code before or after showing the form and not setting the numeric(numeric, numeric password, ... ,other numeric) constraints by Resource Editor solves the problem caused by this bug.